# Машина состояний для бота телеграм

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

У меня есть тг-бот с FSM. Сейчас состояния сохраняются в `MemoryStorage` и при перезапуске бота последнее состояние сбрасывается. Хотелось бы узнать, как:

1. Сохранять последнее состояние
2. Сделать состояние по умолчанию, которое будет устанавливаться для всех пользователей при перезапуске бота. Также это состояние будет устанавливаться для всех новых пользователей.

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации aiogram сказано: *"This type of storage is not recommended for usage in bots, because you will lost all states after restarting."* Соответственно состояние и сбрасывается.

**Не используйте MemoryStorage**, если вам нужно хранить состояние после перезапуска. Храните состояния в базе данных. В Aiogram реализована поддержка noSQL баз (Redis, Mongo, Rethink), но вы можете написать свою обертку. Пример для **SQLAlchemy**: https://github.com/nmzgnv/bot-template-aiogram-flask/blob/main/bot/states/SQLAlchemyStorage.py